# How to add description to image while posting

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

what should I add in code so that it will add description to image

```
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/viewitems.png");

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putByteArray("picture", data);

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines,

```
params.putString("caption", "your Caption message goes here");
params.putString("description", "your Description text goes here");
```

So the key denotes the parameter type and the value gets you the actual message.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know whether key caption or description is responsible for adding description to image.

Comment: I am not sure about description. But I was good with caption and it works for me always. : ) ..